# Using local SSH tunneling with Docker (PhpMyAdmin) - Connection refused

Tags: mysql, docker, ssh, docker-compose, phpmyadmin

I am running PhpMyAdmin using Docker on my local machine with docker-compose. On remote server i'm using mysql user who can only access from localhost which is why i need ssh tunneling.

```
version: '3.1'

services:
  phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8080:80
    environment:
      - PMA_ARBITRARY=1
    volumes:
      - /usr/local/etc/php/php.ini:/php-make/upload.ini
      - ./config.inc.php:/etc/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php
    networks:
      - host

networks:
  host:
```

Since i'm using host network, docker container should be aware of local port forwarding (not really sure about this tho, but i couldn't find much information online on how host network actually works).

SSH config

```
host remote-server-name
    HostName remote-server-ip
    User user
    IdentityFile path-to-ssh-key
    ForwardAgent yes
    LocalForward 3306 127.0.0.1:3306
```

After i do ssh to remote server there should be a tunnel on my local machine on port 3306 that is pointing to 3306 on remote server. Here is netstat -tulpn to confirm that:

```
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3306          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      17506/ssh
```

Server choice configuration for PhpMyAdmin (phpmyadmin.config.inc)

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['verbose'] = 'remote-server-name';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = '127.0.0.1';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['port'] = '3306';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type'] = 'tcp';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysqli';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'cookie';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = false;
$cfg['LoginCookieValidity'] = 24*60*60*30;
```

After i choose remote-server-name in server choice i get the following message

```
mysqli::real_connect(): (HY000/2002): Connection refused
```

which means mysql user in not allowed to access from given ip address (in this case my public ip) and i guess that's because docker container is not using ssh tunneling from my local machine even if i'm using host network (which again i'm not sure what it actually does).

Anyone got any ideas what i'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change your service configuration to say

```
services:
  phpmyadmin:
    network_mode: host
    # and not networks:
```

The configuration you have creates a Compose network that happens to be named `host`, but it's not "the host network".

---

You may be able to use a different approach to connect to the ssh tunnel; also see [From inside of a Docker container, how do I connect to the localhost of the machine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24319662/from-inside-of-a-docker-container-how-do-i-connect-to-the-localhost-of-the-mach).  In particular, if you're on a MacOS or Windows host, host networking just doesn't work (you connect to the "host network" of a hidden Linux VM) and you'll need to use the special `host.docker.internal` host name instead of `localhost`.  For this you don't need any special `networks:` or `network_mode:` option at all.

You might need to change the settings of the ssh tunnel listener for this to work.  The `127.0.0.1:3306` setting binds to the host's localhost interface, but at least on native Linux the request will actually arrive from the `docker0` interface.  Setting the tunnel listener to listen on `0.0.0.0:3306` will solve this problem but also will allow others on the network to connect to the forwarded database.  There's not a trivial solution for this.

Comment: Ty for the clear explanation. I'm using Linux so "network_mode: host" is working. I will try to make this working on MacOS (once i go to the office) and will post another comment about that.

Comment: I aslo managed to do this on MacOS. I completely removed network_hosts from docker-compose file and opened random ports. In SSH config everythig stayed the same (ssh tunnel on 127.0.0.1:3306). But in phpmyadmin config.inc i had to put $cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = 'host.docker.internal';